# How to identify user who created the head revision using fstat?

Tags: perforce

I can do this using filelog. A command such as

```
p4 filelog -m1 -s //path/to/file
```

Produces output of the following form:

```
#51 change 196811 edit on 2014/05/06 by user@client-workspace ...
```

I would prefer not to have parse it. I can't figure out how to do it using `p4 fstat`. I would have thought it would be `actionOwner`, but:

```
$ p4  fstat -T actionOwner //path/to/file

Field actionOwner doesn't exist.
```

Comment: Instead of using 'fstat', you could do 'p4 -ztag filelog -m1 -s //path/to/file'.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I don't have to use fstat. I did not know about -ztag, will try it out. Can you plese convert your comment to answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using 'fstat', you could do 'p4 -ztag filelog -m1 -s //path/to/file'.

It will produce output something like:

```
C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 -ztag filelog -m 1 //depot/a
... depotFile //depot/a
... rev0 1
... change0 1
... action0 add
... type0 text
... time0 1399680148
... user0 Bryan
... client0 Dell660
... fileSize0 10
... digest0 733F328D8CFF7DD89970EC34A70AA14F
... desc0 My super change
```

And you could look at the "user0" field.

By the way, if you have a recent enough client, you can even combine this with the less-known -F option, as in:

```
C:\Users\Bryan\perforce\client>p4 -ztag -F "%user0%" filelog -m 1 //depot/a
Bryan
```

There are lots of ways to skin this cat, but this is definitely one of the ways.

Comment: `-F "%user0%` did not work on my `P4/NTX64/2013.1/659207` but `-ztag` gave me exactly what I needed.